# can we merge $e^2\pi^2$ with a permutation of its decimal digits so its rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

assuming we have the number $4e^2\pi^2  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n 10^{-n}$.
now lets define the number $x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{\sigma(n)}10^{-n}$ when 
$\sigma$  is a 1-1 and onto function from $ N \to N$.

My quastion is if we can find a finite index set I such that : y = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}10^{-n}b_i $ when $b_i = a_i \ if \ i\notin I \ and \ b_i = a_{\sigma(i)} \ if \ i\in I$ and y $\in $ Q?

Comment: We even do not know whether $e\cdot \pi$ is irrational. There is a possibility that we need not permute at all. But in the case $e^2\cdot \pi^2$ is irrational, a FINITE permutation of digits cannot lead to a rational number because permuting the first  $n$ digits does not change the irrationality of a number, no matter how large $n$ is.

Comment: I.m not sure that what you say and what you meant are the same. The word "merge" in the title suggests you want $(a_n)_n$  and $(a_{\sigma  (n)})_n$  as "disjoint" sub-sequences  that when "shuffled together" give $(b_i)_i.$ That is,  an infinite,co-infinite $I\subset N$ such that if $i$ is the $m$th member of $I$ then $b_i=a_m,$  and  and if $j$ is the $n$th member of $\Bbb N$ \ $I$ then$ b_j=a_{\sigma (n)}.$  This is not the same thing as what you wrote but is it what you meant? (If so I  think I can prove the answer is yes.)

Comment: actually put notice that is the same as i wrote (may be my English is not very well) also i meant that $b_i = a_m$ for i which is the m-Th member in finite set I (but of course it doesn't actually netters) , so yes i would like to hear your solution please.